# Erro após atualizar a versão do PIP - Python

Tags: python, windows, biblioteca, pip

eu fui atualizar a versão do pip na minha máquina e agora quando eu vou instalar uma biblioteca aparece o seguinte erro:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (20.1)
Could not build wheels for pip, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
```

Eu já tentei voltar para a versão anterior mas não obtive sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O Ubuntu, assim como outros derivados do debian, tem um programa chamado de update-alternatives.

Com ele você pode configurar os atalhos de chamada de programas com múltiplas versões, com apenas um comando, e alterar a versão de executáveis que tem múltiplas versões.

Não copiarei todo o conteúdo explicando como usar o update-alternatives, mas o site https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux tem um bom exemplo de como configurar, inclusive exemplificando o caso do python, para que você possa usar no seu terminal o comando python/pip e ele chamar a versão certa do python/pip.

Funciona pra configurar o PIP também!

Caso o update-alternatives não esteja disponível no terminal, você pode instalar com um apt-get install update-alternatives